# How to solve the "text index required for $text query" 500 status code error?

Tags: node.js, search

I try to implement a search API. Here is the router

```
  router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const options = {
        ownerId: req.user['id'],
        search: req.query['search']
      };
      const result = await users.getUsers(options);
      res.status(result.status || 200).send(result.data);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        status: 500,
        error: 'Server Error'
      });
    }
  });
```

Here is the log message of the error

```
text index required for $text query (err.code=27)
MongoError: text index required for $text query
```

Comment: You have to create an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is work for me

```
const createTextIndex = function(db) {
    // Get the users collection
    var collection = db.collection('users');
    // Create the index
    collection.createIndex(
      { name : "text" }, function(err, result) {
    });
  };

createTextIndex(db);
```

[Text Search](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/text-search/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).